# Animate Scale of UITableViewCell when Scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am wondering how do we scale a `UITableViewCell` when user scroll, just like the StoreHouse app.

I tried to use the `willDisplayCell` method but it does't work as expected.

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate` and provide:

`- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

You can then adjust the cell constraints or whatever mechanism you planned to use to scale the cell view based on the scroll/cell position.